# Requisição URL Externa Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou com seguinte problema,implementei o código,para pegar informações do blog RSS,contudo não estou conseguindo acessar url criticando erro 401,quando coloco arquivo local funciona normalmente.

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log("Dados" + ajax.responseText);
            startComunicado(this);
        }
    };
    ajax.open("GET", "http://www.infomoney.com.br/blogs/investimentos/off-the-records/rss", true);
    ajax.send();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro `Status Code 401` acontece quando você faz uma requisição, porém não tem permissão.

Já o erro citado no comentário da resposta anterior:

> ```
> "Failed to load infomoney.com.br/blogs/investimentos/off-the-records/rss: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost'; is therefore not allowed access."
> ```

Ele acontece devido a falta do *header* `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` na resposta do servidor.

Para contornar isso, você pode utilizar o site `https://cors.io/`. Ele servirá como um intermediador e adicionará, automaticamente, o *header* necessário.

**Exemplo com Fetch:**

```
fetch("https://cors.io/?http://www.infomoney.com.br/blogs/investimentos/off-the-records/rss")
    .then( resp => resp.text() )
    .then(resp => console.log(resp))
    .catch( err => console.debug(err) );
```

**Exemplo com XHR:**

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(ajax.responseText);
    }
};
ajax.open("GET", "https://cors.io/?http://www.infomoney.com.br/blogs/investimentos/off-the-records/rss", true);
ajax.send();
```

Comment: Grato pelo overview,sobre crossdomain,tudo ok,mas quando tento acessar segue http://blog.linkcom.com.br/plus/ apresenta erro 500?

Comment: O erro `500` é problema interno no servidor (outros erros você pode ver em https://httpstatuses.com). Ao acessar esse site, recebi uma caixa para informar usuário e senha, porém, como não tenho acesso, recebi o erro `401` (como expliquei na resposta).

Answer (score 0):

Faz da seguinte forma

```
                  $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: form,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'http://www.infomoney.com.br/blogs/investimentos/off-the-records/rss',


                    success: function (dados) {
                        if (dados != null) {

                           //fazer o que quiser
                        }

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("Falha de enviar AJAX");
                    }
                })
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Implementei o que você sugeriu aparece seguinte erro "ailed to load http://www.infomoney.com.br/blogs/investimentos/off-the-records/rss: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
ajaxvs1.html:28 Falha de enviar AJAX"

Comment: Vou editar a resposta, faltou umas coisinhas

Comment: Agora aparece seguinte erro;
"Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined"

Comment: só tirar do data:form... você não está enviando nada

Comment: Deu certo meu caro?

Comment: Não.Apresenta o mesmo erro de antes "Failed to load http://www.infomoney.com.br/blogs/investimentos/off-the-records/rss: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Você já tem algum lugar pra hospeda-lo?

Comment: Meu retorno aqui deu certinho

Comment: Se seu problema foi solucionado por favor marque como Resolvido. Pode ser util para outros com o mesmo problema